# How to implement Publishing subscriber Replication topology in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to implement Publishing subscriber Replication topology in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

First, work out what kind of replication you want, and so on.

Also, read through something like the Help system (SQL Books Online) to understand the various Agents that will play a part. Such as the Log Reader agent, the Distribution Agent, and so on. Think about what users you want to use for these.

Then just go into SQL Management Studio, connect to your source, go to the Replication bit and use the New Publisher wizard. Once that's done, go to your Subscriber and set up Subscribers in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Publishing subscriber Replication topology"?

In one sense (the "traditional" sense), SQL Server doesn't support a pub / sub model for replication, where a single publisher multicasts data out to many subscribers.

In another sense, all forms of replication are pub / sub, in that there is a central Publisher that provides data to one or more Subscribers, by way of a Distributor and Agents (but it's actually serial unicast).